# How to get values from BehaviorSubject after sync click?

Tags: angular, rxjs

```
private selectedDocuments$: BehaviorSubject<Document[]> = new BehaviorSubject<Document[]>([]);
public selectedDocumentsFilesIds$ = this.selectedDocuments$.pipe(map((docs) => docs.map((doc) => doc.iD_FILE))).pipe(shareReplay(1));
```

I add a new values using this:

```
setSelectedDocuments(documents: Document[]): void {
    this.selectedDocuments$.next(documents);
}
```

I try to get last emitted values from `selectedDocumentsFilesIds$` inside component:

```
public onClick() {
    this.documentsRepository.selectedDocumentsFilesIds$.toPromise().then((ids: number[]) => {
                if (ids.length == 0) {
                    return;
                }
    });
}
```

Why it does not work for me, there are any errors.

But this works:

```
this.documentsRepository.selectedDocumentsFilesIds$.subscribe((r) => console.log(r));
```

I have tried this:

```
  public createReestr() {
        this.documentsRepository.selectedDocumentsFilesIds$
            .pipe(
                tap((ids: number[]) => {
                    if (ids.length == 0) {
                        return throwError('Message');
                    }
                }),
                filter((ids: number[]) => ids.length > 0),
                tap((ids: number[]) => (this.dialogConfig.data = { data: { ids }, width: '500px' })),
                concatMap(() =>
                    this.dialog
                        .open(DialogDocumentCreateRegisterComponent, this.dialogConfig)
                        .afterClosed()
                        .pipe(
                            filter(Boolean),
                            concatMap((data: { date: Date; ids: number[] }) =>
                                this.documentsRepository.CreateMailReestrById(data.ids, data.date),
                            ),
                            indicate(this.createReestrloading$),
                            handleResponseMessage(this.messageService),
                        ),
                ),
            )
            .subscribe(() => {}, (e) => alert(e));
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a handy suggestion: You don't need multiple *pipe* method calls, you can chain the operator function inside the pipe call.

```
private selectedDocuments$ = new BehaviorSubject<Document[]>([]);
public selectedDocumentsFilesIds$ = this.selectedDocuments$.pipe(
  map((docs) => docs.map((doc) => doc.iD_FILE)),
  shareReplay(1)
);
```

Second you shouldn't call *toPromise*.  It waits for the Observable to complete since a promise only has one emission.  The behavior subject stays open forever so the promise will never be executed.

Therefore you need to use subscribe, as you did when you updated the post.

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to accomplish, but maybe the following example will help.  A subject is created for all clicks, and in the constructor a subscription is setup that gets the last value from *selectedDocumentsFilesIds$* and then logs them.

```
private clickedSubject = new Subject();

constructor() {
  this.clickedSubject.pipe(
     withLatestFrom(this.documentsRepository.selectedDocumentsFilesIds$),
     tap((ids) => console.log(ids))
  ).subscribe();
}

public onClick() {
  this.clickedSubject.next();
}
```

Comment: Could you check the question again, I have done this, is it ok?

Comment: Your update would work since you're using a BehaviorSubject and there would always be a value.  Personally, I typically try not to subscribe to anything outside of the constructor or ngInit.  When you start thinking in streams things can get downright elegant.  At the very least you can return the observable, and have it subscribed to at the highest level possible.  Returning the observable creates more opportunities.

Comment: Could you share an sample, I did not get you right, also why `return throwError('Message');` does not stop stream and allow `concatMap`?

Comment: Are you sure about `withLatestFrom`? It returns array of values.

Answer (score 0):

When using `.toPromise()`, your `Observable` becomes a promise, and will now just emit one value, and then be done.

On the other hand, when you `subscribe`, your subscription will continue getting data back from the Observable on each emission until you unsubscribe.

This is the fundamental difference between Promises and Observables (one async event vs several async events over time).